# "Elasticsearch" search documents before index refresh

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am writing a **php** application that stores data in **Elasticsearch**. I want to be able to search for latest indexed data from elasticsearch in realtime ( Without the index refresh time barrier ). How do i achieve such functionality?

Note : The following never helped achieve real timeness

```
$client->indices()->refresh();
```

Nor

```
'refresh'   => true
```

-- *Elasticsearch V2.3*

-- *I am Using the official PHP Elasticsearch Driver*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the refresh interval for any index using the following query. . .But usually while indexing documents in bulk this value will be changed to -1, which means never refresh , i will refresh manually. Because low refresh rate may result in performance hits on indexing rate.
go through following link for more details 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk

`

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "1s"
    } }'
```

`

Comment: Well, that means the data will be available for search after the refresh is done( A delay from when the data was indexed to when the data is available for search ). Is there a way i can cut down the delay?

Comment: I dont think there is any other way . . .